# Azure DevOps Pipelines Taskgroups Add DNS Record (onprem)

Tags: powershell, dns, devops

I can't seem to find the answer to this one.
We have Devops servers on premises.
I have created a dedicated service account in Active Directory for the purpose of adding DNS records.
I am trying to add a DNS CNAME record using Powershell in the Pipeline. It sadly refuses to work as a dnsAdmin. I have been through the motions and setup delegation and all the required rights for an account to manage DNS records. I have tested the account and it can add/delete the DNS records without elevation so I am 100% certain the user account is NOT the problem.

On our server I installed "RSAT: DNS Tools" and using 
add-dnsServerResourceRecordCName it works from the powershell running as the service account.

So I added this script to devops pipeline as a "Run Inline Powershell"

```
param (
    [string]$cname,
    [string]$hostname,
    [string]$zone,
    [string]$dnsServer,
    [string]$username,
    [string]$password
)

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dnsServer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
    $cname = $using:cname
    $zone = $using:zone

    $existing = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name $cname -ZoneName $zone -RRType CName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
    if ($ProcessError) {
        Write-Host "Adding CName $cname for $using:hostname.$zone."
        add-dnsServerResourceRecordCName -name $cname -HostNameAlias "$using:hostname.$zone." -ZoneName "$zone" 
    } else {
        $hostname = $existing.RecordData.HostNameAlias
        Write-Host "$cname exists as $hostname"    
    }
}
```

However I keep getting permission denied errors.
I have also tried other Powershell techniques, such as using start-process and $sessions and running scripts, I have checked that it is not a double hop issue. And we have a long established Winrm environment, we use Powershell script daily in our business so we know that they work. Bear in mind we have run the above script and passed params to it as the service account user and it works from several different workstations including the current web server.

To prove my setup is working  I added the account to the domain admins group, queued it up in DevOps and  everything works as expected. the DNS record was created as expected.
So we know it has to with with access that domain admin has, that service account doesn't.

Is there any chance someone here has a an answer to this problem?

Chad

Comment: Is the service account you using a member of DnsUpdateProxy?

Comment: Good Suggestion, although I have never really understood if DnsUpdateProxy was intended for machine accounts or users. It is for allowing clients to update on behalf of DHCP.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have tried that and it did not work.